# How to get reductio to work with crossfilter2 using webpacker in Rails 6

Tags: webpack, crossfilter, reductio

I'm in the midst of upgrading my app from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0, and am also trying to migrate some things over to webpacker, including `crossfilter` (which is now `crossfilter2`) and `reductio`, and after spending several hours, I'm no closer on figuring out how to resolve the following error.

In reductio's `value-count.js`, the top line is `var crossfilter = require('crossfilter2');`, and within the code itself, it calls `crossfilter.bisect.by(function...`.  When I try to render my `dc` charts (which worked before moving over to webpack), my Chrome developer console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'by' of undefined at value-count.js:38
```

It was caused by `crossfilter.bisect`'s returning `undefined`.  So I dug a little deeper.  In my own code that's calling `crossfilter` (a JS template that is called via AJAX), `console.log` showed that `crossfilter` is a function, which is as expected.

When I modified `reductio`'s `value-count.js` and added a `console.log` statement inside the `initial` callback, it showed the `crossfilter` as a Module, with a `default` attribute containing the function `crossfilter`.

When I removed `var crossfilter = require('crossfilter2');` from `value-count.js`, my app code worked again, presumably because I defined `crossfilter` in my `application.js.erb` (see below), which imported it as a function.  So it seems like an inconsistency inside the `reductio` code itself, but since I'm new to webpack, I feel like I might be missing something in the `import` statements.

#### Question: How can I get `reductio` to use my global reference to `crossfilter` without modifying the `reductio` source files?

---

My environment:

```
ruby: 2.6.5
Rails: 6.0.2.1
crossfilter2: 1.5.2
reductio: 0.6.3
```

Here's the relevant code in my `app/javascript/packs/application.js.erb` (it took me several hours to figure this out):

```
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';
window.crossfilter = crossfilter;

import reductio from 'reductio';
window.reductio = reductio;
```

I'd greatly appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you back out to crossfilter2@1.4? I think this is probably similar to [this Angular issue](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/147), not in the specifics but in the ambiguity we have between crossfilter as a function and crossfilter as a module. Specifically, some build systems do not like a module that is also a function, which is the way crossfilter was always defined.

Comment: Hi, and thanks @gordon for letting me know about this question! The way Reductio works right now with regards to modules is not something I'm happy with. Fortunately, we are about to merge a pull request that moves to using ES6 modules and a more standard build and module exposure approach. It will still expose a global and consume Crossfilter globals, but I hope it works better with build systems. Would you be willing to try the pull request and see if that works better for you? https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio/pull/60

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I tried downgrading to crossfilter2@1.4 (it installed 1.4.8), but the problem persisted.

Comment: @Ethan, your answer worked!